# Get content after a node

Tags: java, jsoup

I have this html block as below after getting a web-page:

```
<td class="detail" id="ar-content-html">  
<div style="float:right; padding: 10px">  
</div>  
<p>&nbsp;</p>foo<div style="padding: 20px">bar</div> 
</td>
```

How can I get the content of the block after first`div` tag?

The required part: `<p>&nbsp;</p>foo<div style="padding: 20px">bar</div>`

Comment: Can you post little bit clear that what are the content and after which div you want to get your content ?

Comment: Sorry Vaibhav Jain, my English skill is not so good.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use JSoup for this. The code sample that can be used is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String demo = "<td class='detail' id='ar-content-html'><div style='float:right; padding: 10px'></div><p>&nbsp;</p>foo<div style='padding: 20px'>bar</div></td>";

    Document document = Jsoup.parse(demo);
    Element options = document.select("div").first();

    Elements siblings = options.siblingElements();

    List<Element> sibling = siblings.subList(1, siblings.size());

    Iterator<Element> sibIterator = sibling.iterator();

    while (sibIterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(sibIterator.next().toString());
    }

}
```

The output will look like:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div style="padding: 20px">
 bar
</div>
```

To print foo as well, the following code works:

```
    List<Node> siblings = options.siblingNodes().subList(1, options.siblingNodes().size());

    Iterator<Node> sibIterator = siblings.iterator();

    while (sibIterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(sibIterator.next().toString());
    }
```

Output is:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
foo
<div style="padding: 20px">
 bar
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution loses `foo`.

Comment: Oh it skipped my notice that foo wasn't being printed. Changing Element to Node prints foo as well, made dits to my earlier post

Answer (score 0):

Do not invent the bicycle and just use standard `String` methods:

```
static final String DIV = "<div style=\"float:right; padding: 10px\">";

String html = .... ; // here is your html content
String part = html.substring(html.indexof(DIV) + DIV.length());
part = part.substring(0, part.indexof("</div>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Element td = doc.select("td.detail").first();   

List<Node> tdChildren = td.childNodes();

String p   = tdChildren.get(1).toString(); // will select <p>&nbsp;</p>
String foo = tdChildren.get(2).toString(); // will select foo       
String div = tdChildren.get(3).toString(); // will select <div style="padding: 20px">bar</div>

System.out.println(p + foo + div);
```

Output:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>foo<div style="padding: 20px">
 bar
</div>
```